# Custom Routing in ReactJs with Authentication

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, react-native, authentication

Hey JavaScript enthusiasts!

What are some good alternatives to using React Router?
Please also provide some suggestions as to what you use for route access: auth [true|false], roles, etc.

I've been building custom routers for awhile due to authentication requirements in various web applications. This is useful when multiple base templates are necessary: dashboards, admin portals, shops, consumer facing sites, etc. But as you go deeper into the app, more and more nesting occurs till you eventually end up with numerous routers in one app which is unfavorable and gets messy. Not to mention hard to maintain at different levels of the application.

Some things I've tried in the past:

- Mapping a JS file of arrays with routes and filtering on certain properties. There could be an array for open routes, admin routes, and other auth routes in general. The routes themselves are objects with different properties details the route like auth [true|false], route name, roles, path, component, etc.
- Query strings with switch statements.
- Ternary operators (rare, but can be effective/cleaner if there are only two options to render).

If it helps with answers, I primarily use stateless functional components with hooks to manage state. I'm open to using stateful components if you can provide good reasoning behind why and how it can be more effective. Also, if there is a more efficient way to map and filter the routes let me know!

Thanks in advance!